# Migrate data from Magento ver. 2.3.2 to Magento ver. 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, migration

I have a website with Magento ver. 2.3.2 and I need to move data from it to a new website with Magento ver. 2.3.5

I need to copy all (Categories, products, customer, and orders) with corresponding images

Any ideas or ready-made extension I can use to do this

NOTE: the new website has a different theme so I can not take the whole database and replace it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just copy the specifc tables from the old database to the new database. This is easy when you are using phpmyadmin. Before you start, add a prefix to the original tables in the new database (for example "backup") or delete them.

Comment: Can you list of tables needed to move the needed data (Categories, products, customer, and orders) ?

Comment: If I were you I would try to copy all tables without `core_config_data`, `theme`, `theme_file` and maybe others which you dont need. Just look at the table names, the interesting ones are starting with `cataloginventory_`,`catalogrule`,`catalogsearch_`,`catalog_`,`cms_`,`customer_`,`eav_`,`email_`,`inventory_`,`newsletter_`,`quote_`,`sales_`. You also need `url_rewrite`

Comment: thanks, Black for your answer, but I faced some issues with this way. as the old version contains some different extension that the newer version :( So when I moved all tables I had some conflicts

Comment: Then you have to also copy the extension tables I guess or manually solve the conflicts.